# How to tell if smart invert is enabled with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible to see if iOS 11’s Smart Invert is enabled using either JavaScript or CSS? I’d like my websites to work with it, seeing I (and probably a lot of other people) use it a lot.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44470786/how-to-tell-smart-invert-in-ios-11-not-to-invert-my-app-colors-and-detect-if-it

Comment: That’s not CSS.

Comment: It’s the only question related. Had it been answered with a css or JavaScript answer I would had closed yours. I posted it for information

Answer (score 0):

Based on [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44549383/711674) posted in the comments above and using [Modernizr.js](https://modernizr.com/) you could do this fairly easily with a [custom test](https://modernizr.com/docs#modernizr-addtest).

```
Modernizr.addTest('colorinvert', accessibilityIgnoresInvertColors in window && !accessibilityIgnoresInvertColors);
```

This will add a class to the page's `<html>` element called `colorinvert` if the colors are being inverted, and `nocolorinvert` if not.

This should make it easy to apply custom css or javascript logic when the colors are inverted.

Vanilla js could analyze this property and do the same thing as modernizr as well -- something like this run during initial page load should work:

```
var classname = "colorinvert";
if(typeof(window["accessibilityIgnoresInvertColors"]) === "undefined" || accessibilityIgnoresInvertColors) classname = "no" + classname;

document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].classList.add(classname);
```

Comment: And in plain JS?

Comment: classList.add might be cleaner

Comment: Good point, edited.  I'm too used to supporting IE8, but most people don't need that :)

Comment: Yeah, I recently stopped that when our office upgraded :)

Comment: accessibilityIgnoresInvertColors is not defined?