# Disable smart invert in launch screen

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, accessibility

In my app, I have a dark launch screen and, hence, I would like to disable "smart" invert for the launch screen.
[In a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44470786/how-to-tell-smart-invert-in-ios-11-not-to-invert-my-app-colors-and-detect-if-it), I found, that in any view, I can just do:

```
accessibilityIgnoresInvertColors = true
```

However, I obviously cannot get a hold of my launch screen's view.
Is there some hidden .plist setting, or any other steps I can take?

Answer (score 0):

call below function in your willFinishLaunchingWithOptions of your AppDelegate :

```
func appAppearanceConfig(){
        NotificationCenter.default
            .addObserver(forName: UIAccessibility.invertColorsStatusDidChangeNotification,
                         object: nil,
                         queue: OperationQueue.main) {_ in
                            if UIAccessibility.isInvertColorsEnabled {
                                UIView.appearance().accessibilityIgnoresInvertColors = true
                            }
        }
    }
```