# iOS Launch Screen Ignore Smart Invert

Tags: ios, objective-c, launch-screen

We have the accessibility option

```
accessibilityIgnoresInvertColors
```

if we would like our view to ignore the effect of the Smart Invert of iOS 11.

But what about the LaunchScreen? How do I make it to ignore Smart Invert?

(FYI: App is made for low vision people, and interface is designed to be dark by default. They make other apps dark with Smart Invert, but this app should ignore this setting, as it would make it light instead of the wanted dark.)

I have seen this:

[Disable smart invert in launch screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54543411/disable-smart-invert-in-launch-screen)

but sadly there is no answer. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not missing anything, at the time of writing (iOS 12.2) there is no way to have any code have any impact on the launch screen.

Comment: Agreed. Fingers crossed for iOS 13!